# Powerbi to aws s3 bucket connection getting module reference error while refresh the dataset at powerbi service

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, powerbi

I am unable refresh the report at power bi service: scenario i have need to pull the data from aws s3 location to power bi, this i can able to achieve through python script at powerbi desktop level and the i have published to power bi service trying to refresh the report getting an error like module reference error how i can achieve this process to extract the data from s3 location

I want to extract the csv files from s3 location to power bi service